# Wireless Printing on Thermal Printers from Web Based Point of Sales

Tags: android, linux, web-services, printing

I'm working on a simple Point of Sale software using django. For the uninitiated, that means a Web Based Point of Sale. I'm dewelving now in the alternatives for printing using those small thermal printers and I need some help in this.

In the setup I'm working on there will be a headless server and multiples android tablets connected thru wifi. Ideally, I would like a wireless thermal printer and I found some models but I wonder about the software side of this. Which printer servers do you recommend? Would be possible to install clients for this in android? Would be Google's Cloud Printing an alternative?

As you can see, I'm very much in the dark on this issue.

Thanks